# Permission denied linux mail command

Tags: linux, sendmail, postfix, opensuse

I ran a simple command "**mail**" on my Suse Linux 11.1 box and it's display "**/var/mail/john: Permission denied**"

I had two users, john and peter

When I login as peter and ran "mail" it display the same error when I login as john

"**/var/mail/john: Permission denied**"

I'm using postfix as my MTA.

Your help will be much appriciated.

---

Thanks guys,

Here's the output from the command `ls -l /var/mail`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2011-08-06 11:54 /var/mail -> spool/mail
```

Here's the out output when I run `echo $MAIL`

```
/var/mail/john
```

I login with different user and run `echo $MAIL` it output the same line  `/var/mail/john`

Comment: `ls -l /var/mail/` could help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: In addition to the above output, the output of `echo $MAIL` would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The user is probably not in the `mail` group.

You can run `groups`
to check in which groups you are.
As said we also need the output of `ls -l /var/mail`

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed a similar issue which arose after I had migrated /home and /var/spool/mail from another system.  The owners, groups and perms were all correct... yet I was still getting this error.  I tarred them with "tar cvfp" and untarred them with "tar xvfp" and MAGICALLY, this corrected the problem!

There must have been some bogus ACL's or resource forks or some other kind of bad mojo on the files.  Whatever.  The main thing is, the voodoo worked.